# reference a figure containing a `tikzpicture` with autoref

Tags: hyperref

I use `hyperref` for referencing all my figures and it works great for everything except figures `tikzpicture`. For figures containing a graphic, the reference outputs **Figure N**. for tikz, it outputs **section N** of the nearest parent section.

Here is my sample code given:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\section{my-section}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(n) {$n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{my-label}
\caption{my caption}

\end{figure}

aa \autoref{my-label} bb

\end{document}
```

It outputs **aa section 1 bb**. My desired output is **aa Figure 1 bb**.

Comment: Put the `\label` after the `\caption`.

Comment: or even inside it: `\caption{my caption\label{my-label}}`

Comment: That was it. Thank you 1000 times.